# Need script solution for SharePoint 2013 list? It returns all names vs just the active ones

Tags: 2013, spservices

Anyone have a solution as to what is missing in this script:  It returns all the names in the list vs just the active ones?

```
    function OpenEmpReport()
{
var webURL = 'https://....................';
var emp = $("input[title='empRptSelect']").val();
var employee;

$().SPServices({
   webURL: webURL,
   operation:'GetListItems',
   listName:'Employee',
   async: false,
   CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
                                             "<FieldRef Name='ID' />" +
                               "</ViewFields>",
            CAMLQuery:
                   "<Query>" +
                         "<Where>" +
                         "<And>" +
                               "<Eq>" +
                                         "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                                              "<Value Type='Text'>" + emp +
                                "</Eq>" +
                                 "<Eq>" +
                                         "<FieldRef Name='Employee_x0020_Type' />" +
                                              "<Value Type='Choice'>" + Active +
                                "</Eq>" +
                         "</And>" +
                         "</Where>" +
                   "</Query>",
   completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            response = xData.responseText;
           //alert(response);
           $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function()
                   {
                    employee = $(this).attr('ows_ID');
                });
      }
});//get employee id

var empUrl = "https://...............................aspx?ID=";
          empUrl=empURL+employee;
          window.parent.location.replace(empURL);
        window.close;
}
```

Comment: Please remove the image and use the code editor to add the actual code to your question. Also in your CAML - is 'active' a variable?

Comment: ok code now added.

Comment: "<Value Type='Choice'>Active</Value></Eq>" should do it.

Comment: That's what I thought but didn't work. So strange

Comment: I would try to split the CAML query and debug using F12 developer tools. Any change if you just try to get the items where Employee Type is active?

Comment: https://www.u2u.be/software U2U CAML query builder is good to test out your queries as well.

Comment: If I comment out the Employee Type statements the form works fine and returns all the employee names - however I just want it to display the employee names that are active.   I know I have the correct internal name for the column so I don't see what is missing

Comment: It look's fine to me to - try flipping it around and remove the Title/Emp filter and just try to query the active ones